# Drupal Commerce PayPal Payflow Pro Module

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, payment-gateway, payment, drupal-commerce

I have been struggling to enable this module that is maintained by the Commerce Guys.  I have read all of the documentation for this module, but upon trying to enable it It gives me an error for trying to redeclare a class:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare commerce_payflow_pro_server_url() (previously declared in /nfs/c06/h06/mnt/93760/domains/accuairtest.com/html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/commerce_paypal/modules/payflow/commerce_payflow.module:1344) in /nfs/c06/h06/mnt/93760/domains/accuairtest.com/html/sites/all/modules/commerce_payflow_pro/commerce_payflow_pro.module on line 427

I have tried everything I can think of and documented it here: https://drupal.org/node/2115325

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple different solutions, the problem stemmed from the module Payflow links that is enabled by default.  That is what made Drupal think the same class being called again.